# Getting Contact Form from Bootstrap Template Working With GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, github-pages

I'm having trouble making my contact form working on GitHub Pages as they provide static websites, or so I've heard. I've been trying to use Formspree as its been referred to in other StackOverflow Questions with the same issue and I also read this [post](https://blog.reecreate.com/sending-contact-form-emails-from-your-github-pages-site-using-ajax-formspree-c7b17e3f5b0b#.1v0j3cjwq). Here is my current HTML/JS code from the Boostrap Agency Template:

```js
$(function() {

    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" action="http://formspree.io/allenlao26@gmail.com" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" name="_replyto" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Your Message *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                <div id="success"></div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl" value="Send">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Also this is the PHP File:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields

if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'http://formspree.io/allenlao26@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: http://formspree.io/allenlao26@gmail.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

Right now, when I try to send an email on my page, my error message pops up saying that the mail server is not responding. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old post but was having the same problems yesterday. Looking at your code it seems that the JS and PHP are still in control and not allowing formspree to do its job.

I was able to get the a form to work with some help from this post on Codepen https://codepen.io/mblode/details/yNaxYZ/

I used that information to modify (the modification is only for HTML, I was able to delete the JS and PHP) my form page but keep the original styling here is my example:

```
    <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center">Let's work together</h2>
    <hr>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <form action="https://formspree.io/you@your.com" role="form"   method="POST" autocomplete="on">
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="5" width="100%" placeholder="Tell me about your project" required></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
                <div>
                  <!-- Extra field to avoid spam by fooling scrapers. If a value is provided, the submission will be silently ignored. -->
                  <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
                </div>
              <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
                <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New submission!" />
              </div>
              <br>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>     
</section>
```

You may be able to modify it for your use. the key component was:

```
    <form action="https://formspree.io/bill@kearneybillt.com" role="form" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
```